# Questions about USB system architecure

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host

I am reading about USB system architecture. A couple of things are not quite clear from the description on the Internet.

- Is the USB controller on the host called "host controller"?
- Are PHY and SIE parts of the controller itself?
- Considering a typical USB connection when a USB device is plugged into the computer, do both sides have identical controllers?

Answer (score 3):

> Is the USB controller on the host called "host controller"?

Yes, and this is the “computer side”. (At least for typical USB A connections, through 3.1 or so, not sure if 3.2 USB-C changes this, but I doubt it would, it might just be that there is some sort of negotiation if you plug two host capable devices together). An interesting possibility is that many/most computers might have multiple host controllers (not necessarily even the same controller!) to accommodate the desired number of USB endpoints (ports, or internal devices like a webcam or card reader, etc).

> Are PHY and SIE parts of the controller itself?

Not sure, but looks like yes to me, at least SIE, or parts of it or maybe both.

> Considering a typical USB connection when a USB device is plugged into the computer, do both sides have identical controllers?

No. Definitely not. For “typical” USB (not the special case of two laptops connected via a USB-C the downstream device/peripheral is much simpler than the host controller (saves on cost/complexity). The host enumerates devices as they are connected and is in charge of all the communication and orchestration of which device gets to respond when.

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/3/3803.html

Answer (score 1):

> Is the USB controller on the host called "host controller?

Yes.

---

> Are PHY and SIE parts of the controller itself?

Technically speaking, the physical layer is different from the controller.

In many, but not all, integrated circuits, the controller and the physical layer are manufactured on the same Silicon die.

---

> Considering a typical USB connection when a USB device is plugged into the computer, do both sides have identical controllers?

The controllers are different because the host controller has much more work to do.

A USB device requests the attention of the microcontroller by  pulling high D+ or D- depending on the USB device speed.

After that, all the communications are started by the controller.